# Two gaussian mixture swapped values. Global optimization

Tags: python, numpy

I have data which I want to fit with two Gaussians while keeping one mean global. I have already written program with Python using scipy, lmfit, numpy libraries. This is my already fitted data results (least square):

```
mean1   sd1     A1      mean2   sd2     A2      y0
12.24   10.20   27526   25.50   20.42   30642   499.93
21.43   10.20   27529   25.51   20.39   30616   500.32
25.51   20.40   30599   30.61   10.21   27552   500.16
39.80   10.20   27536   25.52   20.42   30636   499.85
25.51   20.41   30616   48.98   10.21   27559   499.94
```

My function for calculations:

```
y0 + + sqrt(2/PI)*A1/w1*exp(-2*(x-xc1)^2/w1^2) + sqrt(2/PI)*A2/w2*exp(-2*(x-xc2)^2/w2^2)
Sorry, I dont know how to change into normal math formula.
```

This was a test, so correct answer had to be:

```
    mean1   sd1 A1      mean2   sd2 A2      y0
1   12      10  27000   25      20  30000   500
2   21      10  27000   25      20  30000   500
3   30      10  27000   25      20  30000   500
4   39      10  27000   25      20  30000   500
5   48      10  27000   25      20  30000   500
```

As you can see, It fits correctly for independent fitting. the problem is that my written fitting program sometimes "swaps first gaussian and second gaussian parameters values" which means now if i try to set mean2 fixed for every dataset, it will go wrong, because 3rd and 5th data sets are swapped so mean2 wont be correct (but im not sure) (for this example mean2 always has to be 25). This problem is even more harsh in real data.
Basically, as I understand, because my function is f = y + gauss1 + gauss2, and both Gausses are identical, it doesnt see any difference in fitting gauss1 or gauss2 and sometimes mix it up.

Output global fit:

```
mean1   sd1     A1      mean2   sd2     A2      y0
12.28   10.31   28483   25.90   19.77   29169   508.60
21.42   10.42   29148   25.90   20.51   28746   505.21
30.61   9.99    26045   25.90   20.26   32149   499.46
39.84   10.11   26605   25.90   21.44   33000   475.15
48.87   9.49    25000   25.90   23.00   33000   485.45
```

Experimental data to try (dab seperated):

```
321 759 568 567 567 567
322 877 587 585 585 585
323 1033    610 606 606 606
324 1231    639 632 632 632
325 1471    675 662 662 662
326 1745    721 697 697 697
327 2043    780 737 737 737
328 2346    855 782 782 782
329 2632    954 833 833 833
330 2877    1080    889 889 889
331 3061    1241    951 949 949
332 3168    1440    1017    1014    1014
333 3194    1682    1089    1083    1083
334 3142    1962    1166    1154    1154
335 3025    2275    1250    1226    1226
336 2863    2605    1341    1298    1298
337 2676    2933    1442    1369    1369
338 2485    3236    1558    1437    1437
339 2308    3488    1691    1500    1500
340 2155    3668    1848    1558    1556
341 2031    3759    2031    1608    1605
342 1936    3756    2243    1651    1644
343 1865    3662    2482    1686    1673
344 1812    3490    2739    1715    1691
345 1770    3261    3003    1740    1697
346 1734    2997    3255    1764    1691
347 1697    2722    3473    1794    1673
348 1657    2453    3633    1836    1645
349 1611    2204    3716    1896    1606
350 1560    1983    3710    1983    1560
351 1501    1791    3611    2099    1506
352 1437    1628    3425    2245    1450
353 1369    1490    3168    2418    1393
354 1298    1372    2863    2605    1341
355 1226    1269    2533    2790    1299
356 1154    1177    2202    2953    1274
357 1083    1095    1891    3071    1274
358 1014    10211613    3126    1306
359 949 952 1376    3103    1376
360 889 890 1180    3000    1488
361 833 833 1024    2821    1641
362 782 782 903 2582    1831
363 737 737 810 2301    2043
364 697 697 740 2003    2261
365 662 662 686 1711    2461
366 632 632 645 1440    2621
367 606 606 613 1205    2718
368 585 585 588 1011    2739
369 567 567 569 859 2679
```

My script (uncomment for global fit the said part):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, report_fit
# python 3.3
# Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages
# http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
# VARIABLES
show_plot = 1
size_cols = 11
size_rows = 50
nm_start = 320
data_sets = 5
file_name = "5_testas.txt"
intens = [[[0] for i in range(size_cols)] for j in range(size_rows)]
with open(file_name) as f:
    for row in range (0, size_rows):
        datal = f.readline();
        data = datal.split();
        col = 0;
        for datab in data:
          intens[row][col] = datab;
          col = col+1;
#def gauss(x, amp, cen, sigma):
#    "basic gaussian"
def gauss(x, mean, sd, A):
    "basic gaussian"
    return np.sqrt(2/np.pi)*A/sd*np.exp(-2*np.power(((x-mean)/sd), 2))
def gauss_dataset(params, i, x):
    """calc gaussian from params for data set i
    using simple, hardwired naming convention"""
    mean1 = params['mean1_%i' % (i+1)].value
    sd1 = params['sd1_%i' % (i+1)].value
    A1 = params['A1_%i' % (i+1)].value
    mean2 = params['mean2_%i' % (i+1)].value
    sd2 = params['sd2_%i' % (i+1)].value
    A2 = params['A2_%i' % (i+1)].value
    y0 = params['y0_%i' % (i+1)].value
    return y0 + gauss(x, mean1, sd1, A1) + gauss(x, mean2, sd2, A2)
def gauss_dataset_a(params, i, x):
    """calc gaussian from params for data set i
    using simple, hardwired naming convention"""
    mean1 = params['mean1_%i' % (i+1)].value
    sd1 = params['sd1_%i' % (i+1)].value
    A1 = params['A1_%i' % (i+1)].value
    mean2 = params['mean2_%i' % (i+1)].value
    sd2 = params['sd2_%i' % (i+1)].value
    A2 = params['A2_%i' % (i+1)].value
    y0 = params['y0_%i' % (i+1)].value
    return y0 + gauss(x, mean1, sd1, A1)
def gauss_dataset_b(params, i, x):
    """calc gaussian from params for data set i
    using simple, hardwired naming convention"""
    mean1 = params['mean1_%i' % (i+1)].value
    sd1 = params['sd1_%i' % (i+1)].value
    A1 = params['A1_%i' % (i+1)].value
    mean2 = params['mean2_%i' % (i+1)].value
    sd2 = params['sd2_%i' % (i+1)].value
    A2 = params['A2_%i' % (i+1)].value
    y0 = params['y0_%i' % (i+1)].value
    return y0 + gauss(x, mean2, sd2, A2)

def objective(params, x, data):
    """ calculate total residual for fits to several data sets held
    in a 2-D array, and modeled by Gaussian functions"""
    ndata, nx = data.shape
    resid = 0.0*data[:]
    # make residual per data set
    for i in range(ndata):
        resid[i, :] = data[i, :] - gauss_dataset(params, i, x)
    # now flatten this to a 1D array, as minimize() needs
    return resid.flatten()

x  = np.linspace(0, 50, 50)
data = []
# dummy data
for i in np.arange(data_sets):
    dat   = gauss(x, 1, 1, 1)
    data.append(dat)

# data has shape
data = np.array(data)

# Rearange data, exclude 1st set.
for col in range(0, data_sets):
    for row in range (0, size_rows):
        data[col][row] = intens[row][col+1]

# create 5 sets of parameters, one per data set
fit_params = Parameters()
for iy, y in enumerate(data):
    fit_params.add( 'mean1_%i' % (iy+1), value=26.0, min=0.0,  max=50.0)
    fit_params.add( 'mean2_%i' % (iy+1), value=26.0, min=0.0,  max=50.0)
    fit_params.add( 'A1_%i' % (iy+1), value=28500.0, min=25000.0, max=33000.0)
    fit_params.add( 'A2_%i' % (iy+1), value=28500.0, min=25000.0, max=33000.0)
    fit_params.add( 'sd1_%i' % (iy+1), value=15.0, min=7.0,  max=23.0)
    fit_params.add( 'sd2_%i' % (iy+1), value=15.0, min=7.0,  max=23.0)
    fit_params.add( 'y0_%i' % (iy+1), value=1000.0, min=300.0, max=1500.0)

# UNCOMMENT FOR GLOBAL FIT
#for iy in range(2, data_sets+1): 
    #fit_params['mean2_%i' % iy].expr='mean2_1'


# run the global fit to all the data sets
minimize(objective, fit_params, args=(x, data))

# plot the data sets and fits
plt.figure()
print('mean1\tsd1\tA1\tmean2\tsd2\tA2\ty0')
for i in range(data_sets):
    print("%0.2f" % fit_params['mean1_%i' % (i+1)].value+'\t'+"%0.2f" % fit_params['sd1_%i' % (i+1)].value+'\t'+"%0.0f" % fit_params['A1_%i' % (i+1)].value+'\t'+"%0.2f" % fit_params['mean2_%i' % (i+1)].value+'\t'+"%0.2f" % fit_params['sd2_%i' % (i+1)].value+'\t'+"%0.0f" % fit_params['A2_%i' % (i+1)].value+'\t'+"%0.2f" % fit_params['y0_%i' % (i+1)].value, end="\n")
if show_plot == 1:
    for i in range(data_sets):
        y_fit = gauss_dataset(fit_params, i, x)
        y_fit_a = gauss_dataset_a(fit_params, i, x)
        y_fit_b = gauss_dataset_b(fit_params, i, x)
        plt.plot(x, data[i, :], 'o', x, y_fit, '-')
        plt.plot(x, data[i, :], 'o', x, y_fit_a, '-')
        plt.plot(x, data[i, :], 'o', x, y_fit_b, '-')
        plt.show()
```

So, how could I improve my code?
And does global fit REALLY includes wrong means? Because it kinda is close to 25. I have no tools to check it. 
Also, is it normal, that my values are a bit "off" the real ones. For example, I dont get mean2 as 25, its ~25.5 for every data set.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, here is a plot of your data:
[image: A]

As you start with the same parameters for both gauß curves, is is clear that the computer does not know which one should be which in the data. So, what can you do?

1. Set one mean to a low value, the other to a high value. The chance is high that this works, but it's not 100%.
2. Just compare the two peaks, and if the order is wrong, just swap them.
3. If you know that the first peak is always at about 25, just let its mean constant, fit all other parameters and then fit again, including the previously fixed mean. This usually works because during the first fit, the other parameters are very near to the final values. So, during the second fit, the changes are not very large.

I can also confirm that there is an offset of about 1, at least for column 2. It looks as if the x-values within the gauss function are not the same as those of the data.

Comment: Thanks for Your response.
1. I cannot set one to low values, other to high values, because if there is big offset, it just cant fit data with big offset (solution?)
2. I could easily swap after non-global fitting. But I want to make global fitting. In this case it goes straight into solver. Check code for commented line, how I do global fitting.
3. I never know where is fixed second peak. In real systems it can shift in values +/-, thats why I need global fitting - to find optimal value, and thats why its so important to have right number in second column -> to count that approdx value.

Comment: Hmmm, now I got the point. It's difficult. I also have no clue why the global fit should not handle the global peak correctly. May be, you can fit two datasets and find the one peak common to both, i.e. the two peaks with smallest distance. Sorry, I've no more Ideas, but I've upvoted the question.